# Create a collection in a specific child database

Tags: javascript, faunadb

I am working on a multi-tenancy architecture using FaunaDB where each team of users has a dedicated child database.

I am trying to create a collection (`Users`) inside the child database, where data about the team and its users is saved.

I am using Fauna's Javascript client. The following code creates a collection at the top level database, while I am trying to add it into the child database.

```js
        var user = await faunaClient.query(
          q.Create(
            q.Collection('users'),
            { data: ctx.currentUser }
          )
        )
```

How can I adapt it to specify the collection inside the child database?

Do I need to pass a reference to the child database somewhere? Or should I instantiate a new Fauna client, with a key from the child database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the admin key of the parent database you can access the child from a new client based on that secret. Format the secret like so `admin_secret:child_db_name:role`

Comment: I confirm! Working beautifully. Hope it gets documented somewhere, and I hope it gets changed in the future, or it will break my setup for sure

Answer (score 2):

In order to write on sub-databases you need to use a key that points to that database, so yes, you need a new Fauna Client

Comment: Thanks! So I would generate a key for each tenant/child database, save it in a collection in the top-level database. And everytime I want to access the child database in question, I would need to fetch the key from the top-level collection? Is there a recomended way to handle keys?